# Convert jupyter notebook to web application with restricted access

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have a jupyter notebook where i have mainly done data visualizations using plotly. I was able to write the charts as html and attach it to my email . But now my issue is i want to convert it to web app and share the link to users through email and also the link should be accessible to selected users only and at the same time the link should not ask for sign in to them.

I read about mercury and voila but am not sure how to proceed with it as i am pretty new to it. Help please

Comment: your question is a little vague – personally, i don't have any experience with `mercury` but looking at the [repo](https://github.com/mljar/mercury), i would start by looking at the examples – in particular, the sections having to do with converting a notebook to a web app, and also the section on deploying your web app

Comment: I am looking for options other than mercury and voila as i need restricted access

Comment: you could look into using a cloud platform such as google cloud, azure, or aws and look into access control

Comment: Thanks Derek , I tried static website in azure but azure allows only 1 website per container. Do you have any suggestions with azure .I cant consider google cloud , aws or git hub related ones as we dont have license for them and company not interested in one

Comment: Do they just need to interact with the Plotly plots and not have an active Python kernel. If so, Plotly plots interactivity mostly work on static pages. (You could probably make a mock version without the actual code and data you don't want out there to test on nbviewer or notebook{sharing}space to see if it retains what you need.) [notebook{sharing}space
](https://notebooksharing.space/) is private by default because you don't need to have it on GitHub and the URLs are generated in a way others won't see unless you share publicly.

Comment: And if you need full interactivity, I don't see why Voila is excluded because you need restricted access. There's plenty on the repo about making it restricted. See [here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/642), [here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/pull/218), and [here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/issues/216#issuecomment-800063190).

Comment: Related topics at the Jupyter Discourse forum [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/using-voila-as-a-means-for-sharing-notebooks/3333/2) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-do-you-share-notebooks-best-practices-around-sharing-to-external-stakeholders/3617?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 1):

### Solution with login view

You can restrict access to the web apps made from notebooks in the [`Mercury`](https://mljar.com/mercury). Just add in the YAML header a `share` parameter with email of the user that can open the notebook.

Example of the YAML header for notebook 1:

```yaml
---
title: Notebook for user 1
description: Secret notebook only for user 1
share: user1@example.com
---
```

You will need to create user 1 account in the [Admin Panel](https://mercury-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin-panel/#users). Then you can send email for the user 1 with link to the notebook and password. The user will need to login to view the notebook. After login, user will see only notebooks shared with her.

Here is how login view in the `Mercury` looks like:
[image: login view in Mercury]

You can share notebook with several emails, or even with groups of emails (users). You can read more in the [`Mercury` documentation](https://mercury-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication/).

Please be aware that authentication is a commercial feature and you will need a [Pro license](https://mljar.com/pricing) to use it.

How many users do you have? You wrote that you don't want to force users to login. Why? In the `Mercury`, the Admin can create accounts for users with theirs emails and very simple passwords, so sign in should be simple and fast (user doesn't need to register).

### Solution with sending executed notebooks by email to selected users

The other approach might be to use [notebook scheduling](https://mercury-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schedule/) in the `Mercury`. You can schedule automatic notebook execution in the Mercury and send executed notebook by email.

Example YAML header:

```yaml
---
title: Notebook 1
description: Notebook 1 send only to user 1
schedule: '0 8 * * 1'
notify:
    on_success: user1@example.com
    attachment: html, pdf
---
```

The above YAML will execute the notebook every Monday at 8:00 and will send executed notebook by email to `user1@example.com`. The notebook will be in HTML and PDF formats. The HTML format will have plotly plots interactive. You don't need Pro version to use notebook scheduling in the [`Mercury`](https://github.com/mljar/mercury).

Comment: Thanks for your solution but the team decided to host the html in Azure side with restricted access.